# Azure API management services analytics in consumption pricing

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using API management services to expose my APIs, i am using consumption based instance for API management.

I have published 4-5 APIs and products in that. I want to analytics the behavior of my APIs exposed by viewing the http responses and if possible request and response.

What is the best way to do this as in consumption based, i cannot see api analytics in left nav of api management services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of options one can perdue with Consumption tier:

- Use diagnostic settings to store gateway logs in Log Analytics and use it's capabilities to analyze the data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-use-azure-monitor#resource-logs
- Use APIMs Application Insights integration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-app-insights
- Build custom pipeline sending data from policy using log-to-eventhub or even send-request policies https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-log-event-hubs

Answer (score 0):

- As per this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features), Built-in API Analytics are not supported for the consumption tier if you want to use analytics you need to increase your plan.

[image]